# Cannot get SwipeLayout Listener to fire

Tags: android, android-layout

I cannot seem to get the Listener for a Swipe layout to fire.I have looked at the examples and other problems but nothing seems to work.Would really love to know what I am doing wrong.

Here is my activity.main:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

    android:id="@+id/swipe">
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/activity_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:background="#ecf0f1"
        android:elevation="50dp"

        tools:context="com.example.napstar.movieapp2.MainActivity">


        <ListView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:id="@+id/movies_list"
            android:divider="@null"
            android:dividerHeight="0dp"

            >


        </ListView>
    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

Here is the oncreate method for the activity:

```
    ArrayList<MovieModel> moviesList;
    Context context;
    private Typeface tfMedium,tfLight;

    private static final String DEBUG_TAG = "MainActivity";

    private ProgressDialog loading = null;
    private SwipeRefreshLayout swipeContainer = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        // ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
        // See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
        client = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this).addApi(AppIndex.API).build();

            boolean refrshToggle=true;

        moviesList= new ArrayList<MovieModel>();
        context=getApplicationContext();
        this.setFinishOnTouchOutside(true);

        try
        {
            swipeContainer = (SwipeRefreshLayout) findViewById(R.id.swipe);

            swipeContainer.setDistanceToTriggerSync(20);
            swipeContainer.setSize(SwipeRefreshLayout.DEFAULT);
            swipeContainer.setProgressViewOffset(false, 0,100);
            // Configure the refreshing colors
            swipeContainer.setColorSchemeResources(android.R.color.holo_blue_bright,
                    android.R.color.background_dark,
                    android.R.color.holo_orange_light,
                    android.R.color.holo_red_light);

 // Check if the NetworkConnection is active and connected.
            ConnectivityManager connMgr = (ConnectivityManager)
                    getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
            NetworkInfo networkInfo = connMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo();
            boolean isConnected = networkInfo != null &&
                    networkInfo.isConnectedOrConnecting();
            if (isConnected) {

                new MoviesAsyncTask(context,MainActivity.this).execute();
                swipeContainer.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onRefresh() {
                        swipeContainer.post(new Runnable() {
                            @Override public void run() {
                                refreshContent();
                            }
                        });

                    }
                });

               // swipeContainer.setRefreshing(false);


            } else {

                AlertDialog.Builder builder1 = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
                builder1.setMessage("Cannot connect to Internet");
                builder1.setCancelable(true);

                builder1.setPositiveButton(
                        "OK",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                dialog.cancel();
                            }
                        });
                AlertDialog alert11 = builder1.create();
                alert11.show();

                Log.d(DEBUG_TAG,"No Network Connection");

            }


            //set on click listener
            final ListView lv= (ListView)findViewById(R.id.movies_list);;
            lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,long id)
                {

                    // selected item
                    TextView tvID=(TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.movie_ID);
                    String selectedMovieID = (tvID).getText().toString();
                    Intent intent = new Intent(context, MovieDetailsActivity.class);

                    intent.putExtra("movieID", selectedMovieID);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            });




        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            Log.d(DEBUG_TAG,ex.getMessage());
        }
```

Here is where I update the view:

```
  public  void updateMainViewWithResults(ArrayList<MovieModel> result,MainActivity mainActivity) {
            try
            {
             //  swipeContainer.setRefreshing(false);
                //update  main activity here
                ListView listView = (ListView)  mainActivity.findViewById(R.id.movies_list);
                Log.d("DEBUG_TAG", result.toString());
                // Add results to listView.
                Context ctx=mainActivity.getContext();
                MoviesArrayAdapter adapter =
                        new MoviesArrayAdapter (mainActivity.getContext(), result,mainActivity);
                listView.setAdapter(adapter);
                if(listView.getParent()!=null)
                {
                    ((ViewGroup)listView.getParent()).removeView(listView);
                }
                // Update Activity to show listView
                mainActivity.setContentView(listView);

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Log.d(DEBUG_TAG,ex.getMessage());
            }

        }
```

Comment: Can you simplify your code example? There is no need for an AsyncTask when you are asking about UI events.

Comment: What would you suggest?A Handler?

Comment: I suggest removing it entirely since it has nothing to do with your question.

Comment: The reason I added was because I am not sure what is causing the issue ie if it was some sort of a threading issue(not my strong suit) that was causing it, but, next time will ensure my question has more brevity.

Comment: I suggest that you start a new project in Android Studio and add just enough code to reconstruct the issue you are having in your real app. By doing this, you will gain a better understanding of what is going on by focusing on just the relevant details and ignoring all the complexities of your full app. When you are finished, you might solve the problem yourself. If not, you will have a better understanding of the problem so that you can explain it to others and get the help you need. You will also have a minimal code example that illustrates what you are asking about.

Comment: I did try that and I still get the same issue with the swipelayout, which is why I am stumped.

Comment: edit your question and replace the current code with your simplified version. Be sure to include the actual classes, not just the methods.

Answer (score 0):

i think you should remove the LinearLayout.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your `ListView` by `SwipeRefreshLayout`. Your layout structure be like :

```
<LinearLayout>
  <SwipeRefreshLayout>
    <ListView/>
  </SwipeRefreshLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I did try that earlier.Still no luck

Comment: One more try. I test this with simple view demo and works.